# Having problems logging in with a single page site

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, logout

I am having problems with my login process.  I am using sessions and reloading so that I can have a single page site.  On Chrome, this adds a ? so the end of the url (anytime the ? is present, login does not work).  And on both Firefox and Chrome, the login-logout process only works once and then login stops working.  I have an if statement on my index.php page that is essentially:

```
if($_SESSION["LoggedIn"] != true) {
    /*display login button*/
}
else {
    /*display logout button*/
}
```

Then I set my scripts file:

```
    $("#toolbarTitle-Login").click(function() {
        var loginEmail = $("#toolbarTextbox-Email").val();
        var loginPassword = $("#toolbarTextbox-Password").val();
        if (loginEmail != "") {
            $("#toolbarPleaseWait").text("Please wait...");
            $.post(
                'ajax/loginProcess.php', 
                {
                    'email': loginEmail,
                    'password': loginPassword
                },
                function (response) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            );
        }
    });

    $("#toolbarTitleLoggedIn-Logout").click(function() {
        $("#toolbarPleaseWait").text("Logging out...");
            $.post(
                'ajax/logoutProcess.php', 
                {
                },
                function (response) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            );
    });
```

Then my processing pages loginProcess.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

include "../incl/databaseConnection.php";

$email = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$password = $connection->real_escape_string(md5($_POST["password"]));

$sql = "SELECT clientId
        FROM clients
        WHERE (studentEmail = '$email' AND studentPassword = '$password') OR (parentEmail = '$email' AND parentPassword = '$password');";

if (!$result = $connection->query($sql)) {
    die ('There was an error running the query [' . $connection->error . ']');
}

$rows = $result->num_rows;
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
$_SESSION["clientId"] = $row["clientId"];

}
else if ($rows > 1) {
echo 'CHOOSE BETWEEN ACCOUNTS';
}
else if ($rows == 0) {
echo 'SHOW ERROR MESSAGE';
}

$connection->close();

?>
```

Next logoutProcess.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();

?>
```

Comment: Why bother with the `$.ajax()` calls to login and logout if you are going to refresh the page with `window.location.reload()` in their success callbacks?

Comment: @michael because I still need to unset the php session variables...I don't think I can unset the session with js...ahh, shit it didn't paste part of it, hang on

Comment: My point is if the page needs to be reloaded anyway, there is no value to doing any ajax call or JavaScript.  Just link a login or logout URL, where PHP handles the unset() and if necessary redirects back to the original URL (without anything like `?logout`)

Comment: I second what Michael said. It's pretty redundant to do this if you can use the logout file to set all the session variable to `NULL`

Comment: @hazard How would that work exactly?  So if I was logged in, and I clicked logout, it would track the click and reload the page in js, but wouldn't know that I had unset the session.  If I add the statement when my session var loggedIn = true, it would log out during times when I don't want it to logout

Comment: Please use proper salting and hashing instead of using a simple `md5()`. You're users will thank you *when* your site gets hacked.

Comment: @PeeHaa okay, thanks, noted, I'm just working to get it logging in, and then I'll add the proper security

Comment: Use the PHP page refresh not the JS one. `header("Location: http://your.domain.com/bla.php");` this should ensure the session is unset. And I don't really understand "t would log out during times when I don't want it to logout", so you want to logout or not?

Comment: What everyone is trying to say, is by using ajax and then refreshing the page you're defeating the purpose of what ajax does. So instead of using js at all, just post the data to a url, eg /logout. Then handle all requests inside of that, including manipulating sessions.

Comment: @hazard okay, thank you...the login still adds the ? to the end of the url, any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: @Bankzilla right, except then I have to change my url to logout, and I don't want that to change...single page website

Comment: Usually that shows up in `$_GET` requests, don't see any of that in your code tho', I'm suspecting the JS refresh doing this but not 100% sure, I'll have to make a quick test locally to see if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it ended up being a very simple fix.  I did not include `return false;` beneath my ajax post.  This caused the page to reload as soon as I pushed the submit button (this action took place before the jquery fired), which is the natural behavior for `<input type="submit">`. The "?" was an indication of this submission, and showed that no POST variables had not been defined, or they would have been listed next to it.

```
    $("#toolbarTitle-Login").click(function() {
        var loginEmail = $("#toolbarTextbox-Email").val();
        var loginPassword = $("#toolbarTextbox-Password").val();
        if (loginEmail != "") {
            $("#toolbarPleaseWait").text("Please wait...");
            $.post(
                'ajax/loginProcess.php', 
                {
                    'email': loginEmail,
                    'password': loginPassword
                },
                function (response) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            );
            return false;
        }
    });


    $("#toolbarTitleLoggedIn-Logout").click(function() {
        $("#toolbarPleaseWait").text("Logging out...");

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/logoutProcess.php",
            context: document.body
        }).done(function() { 
            window.location.reload(true);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the damn thing working! You will need to use `session_destroy()` in your `logout.php` file and use an AJAX call in your JS, here are the snippets:

In your JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "logout.php",
    context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
    window.location.reload(true);
});
```

And in your logout.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();

session_destroy();
?>
```

This should have the desired result.

To also note, I'm not experiencing the same problem with the ? at the and of the URL, not sure where that is coming from at all. Just provided the simplest solution that works (at least for me it did).

Comment: okay, thanks so much for working on it...I just stepped away from the computer for a few minutes, I'll try it as soon as I get back

Comment: No problems, I'm a little rusty at my `PHP`-fu so I'm hoping a little fiddling around with some code will get me back on my feet.

Comment: okay, I got a chance to try this, this is a much better way of handling the logout script, and I will definitely use your method.  Thanks for putting it up.  The ? is showing up as soon as the login part of the js fires.  I will continue to mess with it, and I'll post what I figure out.